# How to display iAd after the game scene has loaded?

Tags: swift

I am confused as to why this doesn't work. I got an error: `Thread1:SIGABRT`. And yes, I did look at the post about `Thread1: SIGABRT` but it did not solve my issue.

If someone could please help it would be great. It can be loaded without the iAd banner. But when the iAd code is written in the program, it freezes.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var Banner: ADBannerView!

var scene: GameScene!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Banner.hidden = true
    Banner.delegate = self
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    // Configure the view
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    // Create and configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    // Present the scenee
    skView.presentScene(scene)


}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown.rawValue)
    } else {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true

}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error!")
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave:Bool) ->Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!){
    Banner.hidden = false
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some working code for you that just worked for me. This does not even need `self.candisplaybannerads = true` as I had some issues with that. The ad automatically changes the size according to the screen size and is located at the bottom of the screen.

```
import iAd

class viewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var AdBanner = ADBannerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        /* Ad Banner Settings */

        AdBanner = ADBannerView()
        AdBanner.frame = CGRectZero
        AdBanner.delegate = self
        self.AdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-self.AdBanner.frame.size.height, self.AdBanner.frame.size.width, self.AdBanner.frame.size.height)
        AdBanner.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.view .addSubview(AdBanner)

}

/* All iAd Functions */

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
/* whatever you need */
    return true
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    AdBanner.hidden = false
}


func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("Error Loading Ad")
/* whatever you need */
    AdBanner.hidden = true
}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
/* whatever you need */
}
```